# What does {6} do in Django URL dispatcher

Tags: regex, django

I have a question regarding the Django URL dispatcher. I have this url configured:

```
url(r'^posts/([0-9]{6})/$', views.posts),
```

I understand that `{6}` must be the amount of integers after the `posts/`. But how do I dynamically set it so that for example I start writing one post, it will only display `posts/1`?

I want it to show the current ID of the post and it will increase to `posts/2` and `posts/3` when creating new posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not about Django URLs, it's about regexp. `[0-9]{6}` means exactly 6 digits from 0 to 9.

You can set a range for the length, like this:

```
[0-9]{1,6}
```

The first template will accept 6-digit values, like `000000`, `000001`, ... , `999999`. The second template will accept any number from `0` to `999999`.

Comment: Sweet. That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Igor!